# How do I set Perl's @INC for a CGI script?

Tags: perl, module, cgi

I have the following, simplest Perl CGI script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI();
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use Template;

print CGI::header();

foreach(@INC) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

When called (http://[..]/cgi-bin/p.cgi) I am given the following error:

```
Can't locate Template.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /home/pistacchio/webapps/htdocs/cgi-bin/p.cgi line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/pistacchio/webapps/htdocs/cgi-bin/p.cgi line 8.
```

I made sure that Template is installed and indeed when running this program from shell it works (loads Template) and outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5
/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi
/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib
/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
```

Template is installed in `/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi`

```
[pistacchio@web118 i386-linux-thread-multi]$ pwd
/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi
[pistacchio@web118 i386-linux-thread-multi]$ ls
auto  perllocal.pod  Template  Template.pm
```

This directory is correctly listed in `env` and, as previously posted, in `@INC`. In `@INC` it is shown twice, so I even tried to pop it out before calling `use Template`, but without result. From `env`:

```
[pistacchio@web118 i386-linux-thread-multi]$ env
[..]
PERL5LIB=/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5:/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib:/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi
[..]
```

Removing `use Template` gets rid of the problem.

Comment: You say that Template is in @INC, but if you read the @INC in your CGI output, you see that it obviously is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest adding the following to your CGI

```
  use lib "/home/pistacchio/lib/" ;
```

The PERL5LIB env variable is presumably not available to CGI programs.

**Edit** What I meant, any value you have set in PERL5LIB from a shell will not be available.

Comment: oh, it working adding use lib "/home/pistacchio/lib/perl5/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi"

Comment: The PERL5LIB environment variable is indeed available to CGI programs, it's just not the value you set in your user account.

Answer (score 5):

The webserver doesn't run as your user, so its environment isn't your user environment. You can set that up in a variety of ways depending on your webserver. In Apache, you can use the [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html) directive:

```
 SetEnv PERL5LIB /path/to/your/libs
```

That then applies to everything under it. If you have it in a *.htaccess* file, for instance, it applies to everything under that directory.

If you can't do something like that, you're stuck setting the value of `@INC` in each script yourself with the [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma.