# Bioperl library installation in mysql server

Tags: perl, cgi, bioperl

I installed Bioperl and works correctly.
then installed Bio::Tools::Run::Phylo::Phyml and it works good from terminal.

But when I call same script contains it from a browser to using CGI method, I get this error:

> Can't locate Bio/Tools/Run/Phylo/Phyml.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
>   /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14
>   /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl . /etc/apache2) at
>   /var/www/Adol/mafToPhyML1.pl line 14.\nBEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /var/www/Adol/mafToPhyML1.pl line 14.

I got this message from error.log

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680997/how-do-i-set-perls-inc-for-a-cgi-script) is similar to your question. You need to properly set `@INC` in your cgi script. Add a `use lib` pragma to your cgi script with the directory that contains the Bio directory of where your Phyml.pm is located.

Comment: I tried to do that but I had problem. any way it fixed by new installation of a bioPerl library. Thanks

Comment: Hi Alireza, I can't seem to get around this problem. I'm using the most recent master build from git, but I still get this error. Thanks, Mark